# Bootstrap substitute for onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Record ?')"

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsp, servlets

I'm displaying data from database in table using Bootstrap classes with Edit & Delete buttons. Before deleting the record, I'm presenting - Yes No delete confirmation modal box using default javascript confirm box -

```
onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Record ?')".
```

This is working fine and deleting the right record & the code is as below:

```
<form method="POST" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/orgController">
<td align="center"><button type="submit" name="delete" value=<c:out value="${orgList.orgId}"/> class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Record ?')">Remove</button></td>
</form>
```

I'm using Java/ JSP/ Servlet to display and process requests.

What I'm looking for is some sort of an exact substitute using Bootstrap Modal classes.

I've looked up on the internet and found this piece of code that should be doing exactly what I want by using the following javascript code in html head section to get data-confirm working -

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a[data-confirm]').click(function(ev) {
            var href = $(this).attr('href');
            if (!$('#dataConfirmModal').length) {
                $('body').append('<div id="dataConfirmModal" class="modal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dataConfirmLabel" aria-hidden="true"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button><h3 id="dataConfirmLabel">Please Confirm</h3></div><div class="modal-body"></div><div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button><a class="btn btn-primary" id="dataConfirmOK">OK</a></div></div>');
            } 
            $('#dataConfirmModal').find('.modal-body').text($(this).attr('data-confirm'));
            $('#dataConfirmOK').attr('href', href);
            $('#dataConfirmModal').modal({show:true});
            return false;
        });
    });

</script>
```

and attempting to call data-confirm in this way within `<td>`

```
<form method="POST" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/organisationController">
<td align="center"><button type="submit" name="delete" value=<c:out value="${orgList.organisationId}"/> class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" data-confirm="Are you sure you want to delete this Record ? ">Remove</button></td>
</form>
```

However this is NOT popping up the modal window however it is deleting the right table row.

Any clues, guidance or help will be deeply appreciated.